# Polkadot.js and Ledger device compatibility

Tags: polkadot-js, account, polkadot-js-extension, ledger

I linked a new Ledger to the `Polkadot.js` wallet and transferred some refunded DOT tokens into this wallet. But when I opened up my Ledger Live again, the DOT account is showing a `0` balance. Then I went on the `Polkadot.js` Chrome extension and attempted to link this same ledger, it also shows a zero balance AND it showed a different address for the same Ledger:

14TaEDyp2QJovndX21KaiHpynuktGEP9eSTgVswsd6WC5jMp

13NySAb5HVFE786mcizE5CUJ2p3mHWzS5apcYzhxiL4cJgX

The above are those 2 addresses for the same Ledger: one added on the “Accounts” tab and the other on the Chrome extension.

Now I am hoping to contribute some of the DOT tokens to the Unique crowdloan, but I can't transfer my tokens because Ledger shows a zero balance and my attempt to transfer to other Polkadot.js accounts also failed.

Comment: Are you using the Ledger Live desktop or mobile version of the application?

Comment: What is the error that you received when trying to transfer from the Ledger account? Does it fail before the transaction or after?

Comment: What are the account parameters you used when creating the Polkado.js account, usually you have to select "Account Type" and "Account Index", depending on what numbers you selected, you will get a different address.

Comment: I am using desktop version of Ledger Live. I already had another Ledger perhaps that’s what was confusing to the program.

Comment: The error message is TXN version not supported. It never showed up as a transaction to approve on my ledger

Comment: When I used the 0, 1 derivation path, the address generated is 14TaEDyp2QJovndX21KaiHpynuktGEP9eSTgVswsd6WC5jMp. But If I use the 0,0 combination the address is : 13NySAb5HVFE786mcizE5CUJ2p3mHWzS5apcYzhxiL4cJgX. The latter is the address generated by Ledger Live and shows a zero balance.

Answer (score 5):

- Make sure that your Ledger firmware is the latest version: **2.0.2**

[image: Firmware version]

- Make sure that your Polkadot ledger app is the latest version: **11.9170.0**

[image: Polkadot ledger app]

As you mentioned in the comments your derivation path arguments should be `AccountType: 1` and `Account Index: 0` so that you can get the correct address: `14TaEDyp2QJovndX21KaiHpynuktGEP9eSTgVswsd6WC5jMp`.

It seems that Ledger Live allows you to create new accounts only once you have some funds in the already existing account:

[image: Second account]

i.e. Once you create the first account you should deposit some funds to it (no less than 1 DOT to avoid dropping below the [existential deposit](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000168651-what-is-the-existential-deposit)) and then you will be able to create the second account.

The first account is always `0,0` the second account should be `1,0` and have a different address.

The full derivation paths would be `m/44'/354'/account'/0'/0'` and `m/44'/354'/account'/1'/0'` correspondingly.

Note that Ledger Live has some limitations:

- It only detects/creates addresses with `Address Index: 0`
- It will only scan 11 accounts from the last address used

Comment: Things start to make sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen. Update: I transferred the 1,0 account to a 0,0 account because Ledger won’t pick up the former. And I updated my Polkadot app on Ledger. Now things are functioning. Learned a ton, thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I would like to advise that you shouldn't contribute DOT using a Ledger account.  It becomes problematic when trying to access the crowdloaned tokens.  A regular account created on Polkadot.JS / Extension is fine.

As it relates to the Ledger Live and Polkadot.JS.

When adding an account on Polkadot.JS you'll be presented with two numbers for your account. The first is Account type and the second is Account index.  Leave both values to 0 and you should attain the account on Ledger Live.

Each combination of those numbers yields a new address.  You are accurate, there's one ledger device but from that one device you may 'derive' different addresses.